# How to efficiently populate data into winform DataGridView Asynchronously?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a Word-Addin project(just for reference especially in performance). I have a DataGridView where I populate the data at run-time.
The problem is the large amount of data (typically in millions) that I populate in the DataGridView comes from a webService call which is unforutnately takes 10-20 sec in responding to the call. Also there is search feature on the gridView, that I don't want to call web-Service cause I know DataGridView is very Efficient in searching through the GridView. I want to populate the data in asynchronous such that end user don't have to wait for the response, and also word won't freeze. 
I can use thread pool to populate data in asynchronous manner, but search functionality would be ambiguous.
Any Idea how to handle this scenario?
I appreciate any help.
thanks
Regards

Comment: All words and no code makes Jack's question slightly dull.

Comment: thanks for feedback, I did not include code because I need any alternative yet efficient approach how to do that. what I am implementing is a common approach, which obviously you know. I did not think including code makes sense. Pardon me if I went wrong

Comment: You're right in your way. Your particular question doesn't require code to be answered, but including a part of what your current solution looks like would help if we want to help you find a more efficient way. P.S. I am not the downvoter. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [VirtualMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc(v=vs.110).aspx). What this does is
when your DataGridView wants to display an item it gets it from an event Instead of loading them al at once

```
    // Enable virtual mode.
    this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;

    // Connect the virtual-mode events to event handlers. 
    this.dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += new
        DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded);
    this.dataGridView1.CellValuePushed += new
        DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValuePushed);
    this.dataGridView1.NewRowNeeded += new
        DataGridViewRowEventHandler(dataGridView1_NewRowNeeded);
    this.dataGridView1.RowValidated += new
        DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowValidated);
    this.dataGridView1.RowDirtyStateNeeded += new
        QuestionEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowDirtyStateNeeded);
    this.dataGridView1.CancelRowEdit += new
        QuestionEventHandler(dataGridView1_CancelRowEdit);
    this.dataGridView1.UserDeletingRow += new
        DataGridViewRowCancelEventHandler(dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow);
```

CellValueNeeded could look like this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender , DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
    e.Value = $"Row {e.RowIndex} , Column {e.ColumnIndex}";
}
```